# Turn two circuits on and off one at a time

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqWTZT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to use two MOSFETs to supply power to two different circuits. However only one of these MOSFETs can be on at a time. One FET for the first circuit and the other FET for the second circuit.

The circuit needs to be analog, so no micro-controllers. I was thinking of using a 555 timer that outputs a square PWM at around 10Hz. Then feed this into a half-bridge gate driver IC which then feeds the gate of the two FETs. So when the PWM is high (5V) one of the FETs turns on, and when the PWM is low (0V) the other FET turns on while the first FET that was on, now turns off. This process then repeats indefinitely. I'm not sure if this will work with or if someone has a better idea in order to do this ...?

The load that the FETs will be switching is powered using 24V DC and draws about 3A

Comment: An inverter gate could be your new best friend

Comment: You can always feed pwm into RC and then have it as an input to 2 comparators set to different trigger voltages. RC will slow down rise/fall, one comparator can trigger at 1/3 PWM_high and lower, another at 2/3 PWM_high and higher

Comment: Not *all* H-bridge drivers include dead-time; if you need this, ensure yours includes it by reading it's datasheet.

Comment: @Ilya that is a really cheap and easy way, and the dead time is in between those two thresholds! Which can be calculated by the RC time constant

Comment: @rdtsc yes I see that now. Will this work in using an h-bridge in this way? I will need an bootstrapping circuitry since the FETs are not in series.

Comment: It all depends on your implementation. I don't see a reason for it not to work. You can even put a potentiometer instead of RC and tune rise/fall time

Comment: @Ilya "I don't see a reason for it not to work." are you referring to the h-bridge or your comparator circuitry?

Comment: @JoeyB yes :) (both)

Comment: @Ilya thanks. I will try both, but will first the h-bridge as there is less development and then design the comparator part. Please post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed a PWM signal into RC connected to two comparators, which will trigger at 1/3 V and lower and at 2/3 V and higher, which will leave some dead zone (of course you can tune the values/levels). Also, you can tune RC as you wish as well.

Comment: In that case comparators could need  hysteresis. Without that, with long RC constatns (slow rise / fall times) you will be facing multiple transitions betwen low and high state at output around threshold voltage at the input. Depending on the circuit, that could create some issues

Comment: why would comparators need hysteresis if their trigger points are 5V apart?

Comment: I am not sure if in case of that particular system comparators needs hysteresis, but I think that it is something worth being consider. 
Without hysteresis we could end up with switching between '0' and '1' for voltages near the threshold (because noise and long RC constant).  And that could violate driver or load specification.

Comment: There are two thresholds. For 12V supply one mosfet can turn on if RC is at 2V or less, another one turns on with RC at 10V or more. You're really considering some edge case. Unless there is some reason something edgy could happen, I don't see it as any significant risk

Comment: you mean that multiple transitions for long RC are edge case or that they will create an issue?

Comment: I can't imagine any common scenario where trigger levels of 0-2V and 10-12V with 8V hysteresis is not enough. Unless there are some inductive loads and strong sudden current pulls of motors or something?

Comment: I am not worried about that 8V hysterias - for sure is enough. I am talking about individual comparators and their operation. For example, lower comparator produces strong 1 when voltage at input is lower than 1.95 V and '0' when its higher than 2.05V. But anything in between, because of noise, would result in constant switching. With short RC constant it is not a problem, because input is short amount of time in that 1.95-2.05V region.

Comment: Okay, that is a valid point. The borders of what's considered too slow to care about it are a little fuzzy and circuit-dependent, there probably are comparators with build-in hysteresis to just never think about it.